# Understanding ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

Okay, so I think I am stuck with flutter builder a little bit.

I've created simple app, just to make my question easier:

I have a data class:

```
    class DataLists {
  List<ListTile> lists = [
    ListTile(
      leading: Text('Tile Leading 1'),
      title: Text('Tile Title 1'),
      subtitle: Text('Tile Subtitle 1'),
      trailing: Text('Tile Trailing 1'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Text('Tile Leading 2'),
      title: Text('Tile Title 2'),
      subtitle: Text('Tile Subtitle 2'),
      trailing: Text('Tile Trailing 2'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Text('Tile Leading 3'),
      title: Text('Tile Title 3'),
      subtitle: Text('Tile Subtitle 3'),
      trailing: Text('Tile Trailing 3'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Text('Tile Leading 4'),
      title: Text('Tile Title 4'),
      subtitle: Text('Tile Subtitle 4'),
      trailing: Text('Tile Trailing 4'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Text('Tile Leading 5'),
      title: Text('Tile Title 5'),
      subtitle: Text('Tile Subtitle 5'),
      trailing: Text('Tile Trailing 5'),
    ),
  ];
}
```

And main dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning/data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TestTile(),
    );
  }
}

class TestTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestTileState createState() => _TestTileState();
}

class _TestTileState extends State<TestTile> {
  DataLists dataLists = DataLists();
  TextEditingController leadingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController subtitleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController trailingController = TextEditingController();
  Future<String> createDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        title: Text('Input data: '),
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: leadingController,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: titleController,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: subtitleController,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: trailingController,
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(leadingController.text);
              setState(() {
                List<ListTile> tempList = dataLists.lists;
                if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty && leadingController.text.isNotEmpty && subtitleController.text.isNotEmpty && trailingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  tempList.add(
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Text(leadingController.text),
                      title: Text(titleController.text),
                      subtitle: Text(subtitleController.text),
                      trailing: Text(trailingController.text),
                    ),
                  );
                  dataLists.lists = tempList;
                } else {
                  print('Null values');
                }
                leadingController.clear();
                titleController.clear();
                subtitleController.clear();
                trailingController.clear();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test Tile'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
            children: <ListTile>[
              for (ListTile e in dataLists.lists)
                e
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          createDialog(context);
          setState(() {

          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is: I cannot make it work in other way. Can someone change my implementation to a ListView.builder? I am stuck a little bit :(
Key goal:

Idea:
Click on a button -> form appear -> after you press a submit button list is updated instantly
I'll add a delete function later, just learning docs, nothing more.

Can someone review my code and, if no one mind, try to rewrite the same idea, but using ListView.builder?

I've tried several times, but cannot get properties correctly from the form, and update listtile using builder, need help

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) requires a static height, so keep a track on that one. Now, coming to the question, that you want to use `ListView.builder`. You can do via this

```
Container(
  height: give_your_height,
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: dataLists.lists.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return dataLists.lists[index];
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: No problem @Alex You can mark the answer too. This will help other people to decide which one is the most preferable according to the seeker, in this case, it is you :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you! Wanted to rate your answer also, but not enough rep =/

Comment: It is okay @Alex You will get there. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may solve your issue.

```
ListView(
   children: [
        for (ListTile e in dataLists.lists)
          Card(child: e)
     ],
  ),
```

or with `ListView.builder()`

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: dataLists.lists.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return dataLists.lists[index];
  },
);
```

Further Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html